# Send Data to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm developing a program that generates random passwords, but I'm bad at databases. I can generate password, but I want to send the generated password to realtime database with Firebase, but I can't. What should I do?

My code in mainactivity is like this :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    CheckBox num;
    CheckBox upper;
    CheckBox lower;
    CheckBox sym;
    EditText max_lenght;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView) ;
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        num= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.num);
        upper=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.upper) ;
        lower=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.lower) ;
        sym=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sym) ;
        max_lenght=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberSigned);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View pas) {

                String pass = randompassword(Integer.parseInt(max_lenght.getText().toString()),upper.isChecked(),lower.isChecked(),num.isChecked(),sym.isChecked());
                if (pass.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Lütfen Veri Giriniz !!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("Veri",pass);
                    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sifreniz Olusturuldu... ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                textView.setText(pass);

            }


        });


    }




    private static String randompassword(int max_lenght, boolean upperCase, boolean lowerCase, boolean numbers, boolean specialCharacters)
    {
        String upperCaseChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        String lowerCaseChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        String numberChars = "0123456789";

        String specialChars = "!@#$%^&*()_-+=<>?/{}~|";

        String allowedChars = "";

        Random rn = new Random();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(max_lenght);
        if (upperCase){
            allowedChars+=upperCaseChars;
            sb.append(upperCaseChars.charAt(rn.nextInt(upperCaseChars.length()-1)));
        }

        if(lowerCase){
            allowedChars+=lowerCaseChars;
            sb.append(lowerCaseChars.charAt(rn.nextInt(lowerCaseChars.length()-1)));
        }

        if (numbers){
            allowedChars+=numberChars;
            sb.append(numberChars.charAt(rn.nextInt(numberChars.length()-1)));
        }
        if (specialCharacters){
            allowedChars+=specialChars;
            sb.append(specialChars.charAt(rn.nextInt(specialChars.length()-1)));
        }

        sb.append(allowedChars.charAt(rn.nextInt(allowedChars.length()-1)));

        for(int i=sb.length();i < max_lenght; ++i){
            sb.append(allowedChars.charAt(rn.nextInt(allowedChars.length())));
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

}
```

I have defined the things required for firebase, but I don't know where to write in the main part.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 1):

After generating the random password, you can send to the database in the following way:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("passwords").child(/*how so ever you want to nest data*/).setValue(password);
```

This is just a snippet to get you started, you can read more [Read and write data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Comment: thaks for your answer. Where exactly should i paste this code i.e. inside which function

Comment: That depends on how you want to have your app. If you want to directly store this in the database as soon as the user clicks generate button then you should add the code in the `onClick` other wise you could also make another button something like "Save to Server" and when user clicks on that, you can store at that point. It obviously depends on how you want the app to be.